# Godaddy masked redirection to Wordpress blog

Tags: domain

I have a Wordpress blog hosted on Hostinger, with a free esy.es domain.

I also have a .com domain from Godaddy.

I set up the nameservers and redirected successfully. But when I visit the blog through the .com domain, the browser address changes to the esy.es domain, which looks unprofessional (and probably not a good idea for SEO).

So I tried masked redirection. Works, but then the blog theme does not load (white background, no theme at all), and the Wordpress admin menu does not load (even the menu on top does not appear). To make it work again, I had to remove the masked redirection.

What am I missing? Do I need to change something at the wordpress config?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to edit your `siteurl` and `home` options, so WordPress knows where it lives, but your whole setup sounds like you will just encounter new problems each day.

Get yourself a solid hosting plan and keep your files and domain together.

Comment: I would like to try, it can't be SO difficult to have different hosting and domain providers. I'm new to Wordpress, but I'm a developer. I could catch up quickly if I found really good tutorials, but most I found are crap :(. How can I change those options?

Comment: If you can´t find out how to change those values, you are no "developer", you are just lazy. Don´t expect further answers.